# Is it possible to create view-level permissions with Oracle and MS Access?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc, frontend, citrix

We are setting up an Oracle 11g data repository where users connect to views via multiple Microsoft Access front ends over ODBC (versions of MS Access from 2003 to 2010). The Microsoft Access front ends are housed on a network drive and copied on open to a local Citrix session through a published shortcut.

A single Access front end file (with each user opening an individual copy) would connect to multiple views in the data repository, and each front end would have multiple users with differing permissions, which should be user- or role-based.

Due to legacy VBA errors, MS Access front ends cannot be compiled.

If more information is required please let me know - I am worried the question is oversimplified.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the Access part of your question but views can be configured to show or hide based on user roles or permissions. There are several different ways but all of them need at least one piece of information:

Who are you when you connect to Oracle? Are you signing on as a member of Active Directory,  generic role or other?

The traditional way is for each user to have an Oracle account. Then create roles in Oracle and grant select privileges on views to the roles. Finish by granting roles to users.  This gives view_level read.

To implement row level permissions here is one example in pseudo code. This is not intended to be complete or compile:

- user is authorized by having an Active Directory account and password in the front end (Access)
- in the database is a table of AD users
- table of roles
- table of roles the user has
- table of permissions such as read, update, delete
- table of roles and permissions
- use additive permissions if you can to simplify things (IE if you have read and update, you can do both)

A row level permission views can be constructed along the lines of

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view as
SELECT various columns from ......
WHERE  GET_USER_PERMISSIONS(parameter1_in, parameter2_in) = 1;
```

and the function could be something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
GET_USER_PERMISSIONS(parameter1_in NUMBER, parameter2_in NUMBER) 
RETURN NUMBER IS
v_username VARCHAR2(50);
v_count NUMBER(9);
v_can_read NUMBER(9) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER')
INTO v_username
FROM DUAL;

select count(arp.permission_value)
into v_count
from app_user au,
app_user_role aur, app_role_permission arp
where au.user_id = aur.user_id
and aur.role_id = arp.role_id
and au.user_id = v_username
and arp.permission_value = 'READ');
IF v_count => 1
THEN
  v_can_read := 1;
END IF;

RETURN v_can_read;
END;
```

As an example, if you had 200 companies and 20 users and each user had one or more combinations of actions on one or more of the companies you need to build this in your permission tables and then implement with a custom user function.

Of course there are more elaborate ways of doing this including individual column masking using the [Oracle Virtual Private Database](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/oracle-database-11g-working-with-the-data-masking-pack-part-two.html) (licensed feature) but I suspect this is too much.

Comment: This looks good to me. I was hesitant to answer because my experience with Oracle is very limited but I was fairly certain that it must have some equivalent to the "Windows Authentication" option on SQL Server. One minor quibble is that there likely would be no need to provide a password to the Access front-end since the user has already authenticated when they logged in to the Windows network. Their AD credentials should already be available to the Access front-end, which can then pass them along to the Oracle database.

Comment: @GordThompson The question doesn't give us much detail on how users are authenticated and I am not familiar with the Access role model so I just added the minimum needed to get to Oracle: authentication

Comment: @kevinsky My understanding of it (forgive my errors, I'm not an expert by any stretch, just the guy who got assigned to this) is that users are authenticated by AD group on the windows side, and then with service accounts in Oracle.